# Как определить, реализована ли данная функция в ОС?

Tags: c, ос, posix

Вот в частности мне нужна функция `popen()` и в Cygwin'е в `<stdio.h>` она оказалась не определена.

Посмотрев стандарт POSIX, видно, что она относится к расширению `[CX]`, т.е. Extension to the ISO C standard, но в отличие от других расширений, какая переменная должна быть определена для этого расширения, я не нашел.

В связи с этим вопрос: как вообще определить, реализована ли данная функция в данной ОС или нет, и в частности как это сделать для функции `popen()` или расширения `[CX]`?

Конечно это можно сделать средствами autotools или cmake, но как это сделать на прямую? Неужели там столько разных вариантов, что без спец-утилит не обойтись?

Comment: Compile-time. Если нет, просто не скомпилируется :} Это догадка, не обоснованное утверждение.

Comment: Проверка ОС и версии компилятора на макросах?

Comment: Поробуйте вместо `popen` вызвать `_popen`.

Comment: _popen не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Обычно этим `configure` скрипты занимаются: создают пример, компилируют его и определяют соответствующую переменную, которую можно в своём коде использовать.

В свою очередь [`configure` можно сгенерировать, используя autoconf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10999549/4279)

Comment: дополню: `autoconf` — это компонент в наборе инструментов, предназначенных для поддержки переносимости исходного кода программ между unix-подобными операционными системами. всё вместе это называется [`gnu/autotools`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotools).

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно использовать [CMake](http://cmake.org/).

CMake - это мета-система сборки, которая генерирует файлы сборки для других систем сборки. Например CMake может генерировать makefile, проекты MS VC++, файлы [Ninja](https://martine.github.io/ninja/) (одна из самых быстрых систем сборки).

В частности CMake может проверить существование функции, это выглядит следующим образом:

Скрипт CMake:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test_app)

include(CheckFunctionExists)
check_function_exist(foo HAS_FOO_FUNCTION) 
add_definitions(-D${HAS_FOO_FUNCTION}=1)

add_executable(test_app test_app.c)
```

Программа:

```
// test_app.c
#if defined(HAS_FOO_FUNCTION)
#include <foo.h>
#else
void foo() { /* ... */ }
#endif

int main() {
  foo();
}
```

Также вместо `add_definitions`, который добавляет ключи компиляции можно генерировать файл `config.h`.

```
configure_file(config.h.in config.h)
```

Шаблон файла с определениями препроцессора:

```
// config.h.in
#cmakedefine HAS_FOO_FUNCTION 1
```

`cmakedefine` заменится либо на обычный `define`, либо на комментарий, в зависимости от того определена CMake-переменная `HAS_FOO_FUNCTION` или нет.